# setTimeout is undefiend why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to disable a button click for a period of time before next click

like when i click it should wait 3 or 5 seconds before next ablity to click it again so i have this piece of code to do so but i don't know why it gives me an error says :

```
ReferenceError: setTimout is not defined
```

and the button click one and stop forever.

Here is my code

```
module.SynchNotificationWidget = module.StatusWidget.extend({
    template: 'SynchNotificationWidget',
    start: function(){
        var self = this;
        this.pos.bind('change:synch', function(pos,synch){
            self.set_status(synch.state, synch.pending);
        });
        this.$el.click(function(){
            setTimout(self.$el.attr("disabled", false), 1000);
            self.pos.push_order();
        });
    },
});
```

Comment: should be `setTimeout` not `setTimout`. Notice the missing `e`?

Comment: using sublime not professional ide will get me sick :D

Comment: it probably has JSLint plugin, that could be useful if you have these mistakes often

Comment: i hava an other question .. is what i did right ? will the button prevent and deprevent the clicking for a period ?

Comment: because i increase the timeout to 10000 and the button still clicking with strange error  

SyntaxError: missing ] after element list

Comment: @MostafaMohamed - You refer to a new error, but don't show us the line of code where the error occurs and the context around that.  Think.  How can people help you if you don't include relevant info in your question?

Comment: Please don't completely change your question. To ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page. You can link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a spelling mistake. It is `setTimeout(self.$el.attr("disabled", false), 1000);`

Comment: Ok now i got this error  SyntaxError: missing ] after element list

Comment: You will have to post more code on where exactly this error is occuring